# Double Hashing Function Not Working (Code Provided)

Tags: c++

I am reading from a file with 127 keys. I need to insert the keys into a hash table using double hashing. So here was my go at it, here I take an integer value(the key). If the index at that hash table is null, insert the key, else if there is a collision. I use this hash function g(k) = TABLE_SIZE - (key % TABLE_SIZE). The infinity loop is used so that if there is a collision using the g(k) function, then do 2*g(k), 3*g(k) and so on. I'm not sure what I did wrong because when I run this code on Putty, I get a "Segmentation Fault (Core Dumped)". What am I missing here??

```
void doubleHashing(int key){
     index = key % size;
     int iterations = 0;
      for(;;){
        if(hashTable[index] == '\0'){
              hashTable[index] = key;
              break;
        }
        else if(hashTable[index] != '\0'){
             iterations++;
             index = (size - (key % size));
             index *= iterations;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're missing here is knowing how to use a debugger to execute your program, one line at a time, with the ability to examine the values of all variables on each step, and follow the logical execution flow of your program. This is what a debugger is for. P.S. You're running out of bounds.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik is right. I recommend `lldb` or `gdb`. You need to compile with the `-g` flag before using them.

Answer (score 0):

I would first suspect that your hashTable is not correctly initialized to 0 or that you have enough collisions that your collision avoidance is running past your bounds.

Comment: So what I need to do is when I get to the end of the table, I need to go back to the front of the table when I do my jumps?